# Google app engine android generated client lib functions return null

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have a client-server system. The server is app engine with java. In client side Android device with java.

To generate libraries for Android I folowed the steps explained in:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_client_library_for_android_using_maven

In Server class Test:

```
public int getTest()
{
    return 9;
}
```

Using client libs in Android:

```
Test test = new Test();
Log.e("Test: " , test.getTest() + "");
```

`test.getTest()` prints null instead of 9.

But if I get a function with existing parameter in Test class works well.
Server:

```
private int param;
public int getParam()
{
    return this.param;
}
public int setParam(int param)
{
    return this.param = param;
}
```

Client:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setParam(10);    
Log.e("Test: " , test.getParam() + "");
```

Ok `test.getParam()` print 10.

Comment: could you please provide your endpoint code?